# Como relacionar tabla dependiendo del valor de un select en mysql?

Tags: sql

Estoy teniendo un dilema. Tengo mi tabla **compras** la cual en uno de los campos debe tener una forma de pago y dependiendo la forma de pago, se ingresan los datos respectivos.

En este caso las formas de pago es: **contado** y **credito**.
Soy nuevo en ello y había pensado en crear 2 tablas aparte para **contado** y **credito** y relacionar a la tabla **compras**, pero como son dos tablas y solo se ingresará un ID de forma de pago en compras.
Si hago una consulta para traer todas las compras, como sabría a que forma de pago pertenece si solo un ID se puede relacionar a una tabla, como podria solucionar ello?

Adjunto imágenes para que me logren entender mejor.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que puedas recibir ayuda y evitar el cierre de tu pregunta lee por favor  [ask] y de paso provee un [mcve]

Comment: Hola, utiliza 'una' sola tabla llamada "forma_pago", la cual va a  tener 2 registros. 
1. ID 1 Contado
2. ID 2 Crédito
Debes relacionar la tabla "compras" con la nueva tabla "forma_pago"
De manera que cuando que cree un registro en la tabla "compras" quede mas o menos así.

ID MONTO FORMA_PAGO_ID
1    59.00              1                       -> Registro pago contado
2    65.25              2                       -> Registro pago crédito

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utiliza 'una' sola tabla llamada "forma_pago", la cual va a tener 2 registros.

1. ID 1 Contado
2. ID 2 Crédito

Debes relacionar la tabla "compras" con la nueva tabla "forma_pago" De manera que cuando que cree un registro en la tabla "compras" quede mas o menos así.

[image: DISEÑO TABLAS]

Comment: Pero cada forma de pago tiene campos diferentes a la vez, por ejemplo contado tiene el campo modo y crédito tiene nro_días.

Comment: Agrega las 2 columnas adicionales en la misma tabla. 
id, nombre, modo, nro días como not null
Y utilizas reglas para la inserción y para la lectura de datos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración